# Need some help please, cant set Iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I am working with a embedded system that I am trying to set Iptables.

I get this error even though I am root:

```
/tmp # iptables -L
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Screenshot of error:
[image: Screenshot of error]

I pasted the the running kernel config here:
https://pastebin.com/9ycrBWe2

The kernel seems to have been built with modules needed but maybe I overlooked something.

Any suggestions would be useful as I am out of ideas and everything I have tried has come with no success.

Comment: Are you sure you’re running the kernel you built? Are you perhaps inside a container that might have its capabilities restricted?

Comment: No I am running the OEM Kernel / Firmware supplied with the device.  Any Iptables command I run even though I am root gives me same error as if I don't have root privileges.

Comment: You actually don’t need root (for the `iptables` command yes, but not the kernel interface) but the _cap_net_raw_ and _cap_net_admin_. Hence my question. Another possibility is SELinux.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to help me but how can I check if it SELinux? Is there anyway to tell whats going on via log when trying to set iptables?

Comment: To temporarily disable SElinux, you can set it to permissive mode with
`setenforce 0`.